# Issue with javascript and datalist in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an issue with my code, there is a Datalist in my html with 2 options, when the "Azienda" option is selected I want to show the div called "aziende", but when i select "Privato" I don't wanna show that div, but the problem is it show me the div when I select "Privato" too. Somebody can help me?

```
<form class="contact-form" action="#" method="POST">

    <div>
        <input class="lista_c" type="text" list="data_list" name="lista" placeholder="Scegli un opzione">
        <datalist id="data_list">
            <option value="Azienda">Azienda</option>
            <option value="Privato">Privato</option>
        </datalist>
    </div> <br>

    <input class="input1" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
    <input  class="input1" type="text" name="cognome" placeholder="Cognome" /> <br>
    <input class="input2" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /> <br>

    <div id="aziende" style="display: none">
        <input class="nome-azienda" type="text" name="nome-azienda" placeholder="Nome Azienda" />
        <input class="iva" type="text" name="IVA" placeholder="P.IVA" />
    </div>

</form>

<script>
    
    let getvalue = document.getElementsByName('lista') [0];

    getvalue.addEventListener('input', function() {
        if(getvalue !== [0]){
       document.getElementById('aziende').style="display: block";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('aziende').style="display: none";
        }
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Because your `if` condition makes no sense. `getvalue` will be an `HTMLInputElement` so comparing it with `[0]` is useless...

Comment: I guess you want the `.value` of `getvalue` and then compare that with something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your `if` test is incorrect. See comments below for details on the working solution.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact-form" action="#" method="POST">

    <div>
        <input class="lista_c" type="text" list="data_list" name="lista" placeholder="Scegli un opzione">
        <datalist id="data_list">
            <option value="Azienda">Azienda</option>
            <option value="Privato">Privato</option>
        </datalist>
    </div> <br>

    <input class="input1" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
    <input  class="input1" type="text" name="cognome" placeholder="Cognome" /> <br>
    <input class="input2" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /> <br>

    <!-- Use CSS classes instead of inline styles when possible. -->
    <div id="aziende" class="hidden">
        <input class="nome-azienda" type="text" name="nome-azienda" placeholder="Nome Azienda" />
        <input class="iva" type="text" name="IVA" placeholder="P.IVA" />
    </div>

</form>

<script>
    const div = document.querySelector("#aziende");
    
    document.querySelector("[name='lista']").addEventListener('input', function() {
      // Just check the value of the input
      if(this.value === "Azienda"){ 
        div.classList.remove("hidden");  // Show the div
      } else {
        div.classList.add("hidden");     // Hide the div
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison (the if statement) is invalid.  You're comparing the dom element 'getvalue' to an array with a single element of zero.

I believe you should compare the *value* of the the input element, not the element itself.  you're also comparing it to an array? you should compare it to the value you're looking for:

```
if (getvalue.value !== 'Azienda') {
```

to help debug things like this, it's useful to use console.log or alert statements to display the value of the variable just before the test:

```
console.log('value of getvalue input element', getvalue.value);
if (getvalue.value
```